# FAQs Accordion Expanding on Mobile Issue

Tags: css, css-transitions, accordion, padding

My FAQs accordion, upon clicking the question, expands to show the answer to the question.

However, on mobile screens, I noticed that the answer text moves as it transitions into the expansion.

When I reduce the right and left padding of the `.faqs-question p.show` to 0, it eliminates the movement but the lack of padding is very ugly.

Could anyone provide assistance? Let me know if you need any clarification!

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {

    const faq = button.nextElementSibling;
    faq.classList.toggle('show');


    const icon = button.querySelector('.bi');

    if (icon.classList.contains("bi-plus")) {
      icon.classList.toggle("bi-plus");
      icon.classList.toggle("bi-dash");
    } else if (icon.classList.contains("bi-dash")) {
      icon.classList.toggle("bi-dash")
      icon.classList.toggle("bi-plus")
    }


  })
})
```

```css
.faqs-container {
  width: 90%;
}

.faqs-question {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.faqs-question button h3 {
  font-family: 'interstate', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.faqs-question h3 {
  line-height: 40px;
}

.faqs-question button {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  font-family: 'interstate', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #300600;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.faqs-question i {
  font-size: 32px;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.faqs-question p {
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather-Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #444;
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 55px;
}

.faqs-question p.show {
  border-top: 1px solid #999;
  max-height: 75vh;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 20px 0px 40px 0px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="faqs-container">
  <div class="faqs-question">
    
    <button>
        <h3>Which services do you provide?</h3>
        <i class="bi bi-plus"></i>
        </button>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
    </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a tip: https://nimb.ws/IsJLT1 Don't use h3 inside a button.

Comment: I think the problem is caused because of .faqs-question p.show {max-height: 75vh;} This should be max-height:none; on mobile or you use the max-height:75vh together with overflow:auto;